# Calling qgis:postgisexecuteandloadsql from standalone script. DataItemProvider is empty

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I'm trying to execute sql and load layer from script. whcih works fine with qgis python console but standalone script fails.

There may be a proper way to initialize postgresql db settings but so far I have no data how to solve.

```py
import os, sys
# Append QGIS Python library to python search path
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.18\apps\qgis\python')
# PyQt5
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.18\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages')
#processing
sys.path.append(r'C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.18\apps\qgis\python\plugins')
#set qt5 path
os.environ['QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH']=r'c:\Program Files\QGIS 3.18\apps\Qt5\plugins'

import processing
from qgis.core import QgsApplication,QgsDataItemProvider
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.18\apps\qgis", True)

showGui=True
qgs=QgsApplication([], showGui)
QgsApplication.initQgis()
Processing().initialize()

from qgis.core import QgsProviderRegistry
   
#here standalone script returns empty array.
print(QgsProviderRegistry.instance().dataItemProviders('postgres') )

#exception thrown.
dbResult= processing.run("qgis:postgisexecuteandloadsql",{"DATABASE":"mydb","SQL":"select * from table1","ID_FIELD":"id1"})
QgsApplication.exitQgis()
```